# ddcutil causing USB keyboard to fail

Tags: usb

I recently discovered (to my incredible happiness) that one can control the brightness of an external monitor using DDC. I have a Dell U2415 connected via DisplayPort. I use the following command (for example, to set brightness to 75%):

```
sudo ddcutil setvcp 10 75
```

It works! Fantastic.

The problem is that, after I execute the command, my USB keyboard (plugged into any USB port) fails in a strange way. Some keys work. Others do not. It seems as though some keys are "stuck down". If I disconnect/reconnect the USB cable, everything is back to normal.

Any ideas what could cause such behavior and how to work around?

Thanks!

Comment: I got the exactly same setup - Dell U2415 connected through DisplayPort with Logitech USB wireless mouse adapter plugged into the monitor's USB port and I cannot reproduce the behavior you're describing. I'm also using `ddcutil` on a daily basis to automatically turn the monitor off and on with `sudo ddcutil -b 7 setvcp d6 5` and `sudo ddcutil -b 7 setvcp d6 1` and I have never experienced a similar problem. Do you have an additional hub connected to the monitor's USB port?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk  Interesting. My keyboard (plugged into the monitor) sports a hub, though I don't use it...

Comment: Also, what does `clicking doesn't work as I'd expect` mean exactly? From what I understand, you have both mouse and keyboard plugged into 2 different monitor USB ports but only mouse behaves incorrectly after using `ddcutil`?

Comment: I have mouse, keyboard, webcam and microphone plugged into the monitor's USB ports. Both mouse and keyboard behave weirdly after the `ddcutil` command. Most keys on the keyboard don't work (though some do!) and clicking somewhere in a terminal with the mouse causes unexpected text selection... Now that I type that out, it seems reasonable to guess that it's just the keyboard that is acting weirdly with some of the key presses getting "stuck down" for some reason. Weird. Will keep experimenting. Thanks again!

Comment: Just one thought - can you try `ddcutil` with `-d` or `-b` to tell it to send commands to the specified monitor?

Comment: Unfortunately, using -b to specify the bus number doesn't help. In fact, even running `ddcutil detect` causes the same strange behavior.

Comment: That's an interesting problem, have you considered reporting an issue at project's GH page https://github.com/rockowitz/ddcutil/issues?

Comment: Good idea, I will do so after investigating further. One more tidbit: The monitor hub was a red hearing. I get the same problem with the keyboard when plugging into any USB port on the computer. Will update original post to reflect this...

Answer (score 1):

I am the developer of ddcutil.  This is a known problem that was fixed in release 0.9.8.  See [Release Notes](http://www.ddcutil.com/release_notes/).  If you are experiencing the problem on release 0.9.8 or later, please report it on the [Github issue tracker](https://github.com/rockowitz/ddcutil/issues).

As a workaround, you can execute ddcutil with the --nousb option.  This tells ddcutil not to check for monitors that use USB instead of I2C to communicate with the monitor's Virtual Control Panel.  As a practical matter, such monitors are rare.